# NRF51822 UART with ArduinoIDE

Tags: arduino, uart, nrf51822

When using UART in ArduinoIDE, ArduinoIDE uses a preset pin number for RX and TX for UART, and when using a board like ESP32 which has RX/TX pins preset it's fine.

What do you do when a board does not have any preset RX/TX pins but instead allows UART on all GPIO pins? how do you set the RX/TX pins in ArduinoIDE?

(The board I wanna use UART with is the NRF51822)

Comment: I’d suggest you look at the Arduino core code for the nrf51, not the IDE. Usually it is set in the Boards.txt file or as an option in the Serial.begin() method.

Comment: You might be able to do Serial.setPins(rx,tx); before Serial.begin();      The default pin are set in the file variant.h under the variant directory for the board you’ve selected.  You’ll need to find where the core files are stored. A Google should find that for your computing platform.